# How do I migrate Struts application into Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, struts

How do I migrate Struts application into Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Check struts2spring-mvc-plugin. http://code.google.com/p/struts2springmvc/

Comment: Thanks,
Could you please explain in high level?